# how to inserting dynamic input fields value into mysql table using cakephp2.8.5

Tags: cakephp

Please anyone help me, Thanks in advance,I am new to Cakephp. I am using Cakephp 2.8.5 version. In my project I have a form where I am selecting user from a combobox. On selecting user, below text boxes with Course name and price text boxes will appear. This is done through jquery.

But my problem is how to insert username,course name and price into mysql database as example

```
            column 1  | column2                | column 3
            ragith      ITIL Foundation, CAPM    $200,$400
```

My view page is add_price.ctp
Inside this page where you will find

```
                <div class="form-group" id="divprice"> 

                   </div>  where the Course name and Price textboxes are displaying through jquery

                My full view page as below
                <head>
                <?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery.js'); ?>
                <script>
                 $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#user').change(function(){         
                     var nameIdVal = $(this).val(); 
                     $.ajax({

                           type: "POST",
                           url: '/invl_exams/userprice',
                           cache: "false",
                           data: {userid:nameIdVal}, 
                           success : function(result){
                           //alert(result);
                           $('#divprice').html(result);                           

                           } 
                      }); 

                    });

                  });

             // using Ajax serialize to insert into DB

             $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.btn').click(function(event){ 
              event.preventDefault();                         

                 $.ajax({                            
                        method: "POST", 
                        url: "/invl_exams/submitprice",               
                        cache: "false",                   
                        data: $('#addPriceForm').serialize(),                  
                        dataType: "text",   
                        success: function(strMessage){
                        //alert(strMessage); 
                        //console.log(strMessage); 
                          //$('#msg').html(strMessage);  

                        },
                        error: function(strMessage){
                          //alert('error'); 
                          console.log('error');    
                        }            
                     });     

                    clearData();              
            });            
          });

      function clearData()
      {
        $('#addPriceForm :input').each(function(){
           $(this).val('');    

        });         
      }    
                </script>
                </head>
                <body>
                <div id="content">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <div id="msg"></div>
                 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" id="ExamAddExamForm"  action="/invl_exams/users/priceSubmit">  
                 <div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" value="POST" name="_method"></div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="ExamUsername">Users</label>  
                    <select class="form-control" required="required" id="user" name="data[Exam][userid][]"> 
                     <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                    <?php foreach($users as $username): ?>   
                     <option value="<?php echo $username['users']['id']?>"><?php echo $username['users']['username']?>
                     </option>
                    <?php endforeach;  ?> 
                    </select> 
                    <label id="ExamUsername-error" class="error" for="ExamUsername"></label>       
                  </div>

                   <!--On selecting username showing the Courses with price textboxes in this id here -->  
                   <div class="form-group" id="divprice"> 

                   </div>

                  <div class="form-group">  
                    <button class="btn btn-default">Submit</button> 
                  </div>
                </form>
                </div><br class="clearall">
                </div>

                </body>

                routes.php

                Router::connect('/userprice', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'showprice'));

Router::connect('/submitprice', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'price_submit'));

                Controller Page is UsersController.php

                <?php
                App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
                class UsersController extends AppController
                {
                   public function showprice()
                   {
                      $this->loadModel('Exam');   
                      $id = $_POST['userid'];
                      //echo $id;
                      //die();        
                      if($id!=0)  
                      {  

                         $allPrice = $this->Exam->query("select * from exams where username = $id");   

                        $total_price = $allPrice[0]['exams']['exam'];                  
                         $price = explode(',',$total_price);                    

                //This table will be displayed after selecting the user from combobox

                         echo "<table class='tblrow' width='450px'>";  
                         for($i=0;$i<count($price);$i++) 
                         {
                          //echo $price[$i];
                          echo "<tr>";
                          echo "<td><b>Course:</b><input type='' name='course[]' value='$price[$i]'></td>";
                          echo "<td><b>Price:</b><input type='text' name='price[]' value=''></td>";
                          echo "</tr>";
                          echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>"; 
                         }
                         echo "</table>";                      
                      }
                      else 
                      {
                        echo "No results found";                   
                      }

                       die();                  
                   }

         // This function is for inserting into the Mysql database table       
         public function price_submit() 
          {            
            // print_r($_POST);
             if(isset($_POST['data'])) 
             {            
                 $this->loadModel('Price');
                 $priceData = $_POST['data']; 
                 $this->Price->create();
                 if($this->Price->save($priceData))
                 {
                   echo "Data added successfully";  

                 }           
              }     

             $this->loadModel('User');
             //$userData = $this->User->find('all');
             $userData =  $this->User->query("select * from users where id!= 15 and id!= 8");     
             $this->set('users',$userData);            
          }                  
                }

                Model page is User.ctp

                <?php
                //App::uses ('AppModel','Model'); 
                class User extends AppModel{

                  public $validate = array(
                        'username' => array(

                            'required' => array(
                                'rule' => 'notBlank',
                                'message' => 'Username is required'
                            ),
                            'isUnique' => array(
                            'rule' => 'isUnique',
                            'message' => 'This username has already been taken') 

                        ),        
                        'password' => array(

                            'required' => array(
                                'rule' => 'notBlank',
                                'message' => 'A password is required' 
                            ),
                           'isUnique' => array(
                            'rule' => 'isUnique',
                            'message' => 'Password has already been taken')  
                        ), 
                        'full_name' => array(
                            'required' => array(
                                'rule' => 'notBlank',
                                'message' => 'Full name is required' 
                            )
                        ),
                        /*'role' => array(
                            'required' => array(
                                'rule' => 'notBlank',
                                'message' => 'Role is required'   
                            )
                        ) */
                       'email' => array(
                       array(
                        'rule' => array('email'),
                        'massage' => 'Please enter a valid email address',
                             ),
                          ), 
                          'secondary_email' => array(
                       array(
                        'rule' => array('email'),
                        'massage' => 'Please enter a valid email address',
                             ),
                          ),      
                      'phone' => array(
                            'required' => array(
                                'rule' => 'notBlank',
                                'message' => 'Phone is required'  
                            )
                        ),
                        'secondary_phone' => array(
                            'required' => array(
                                'rule' => 'notBlank',
                                'message' => 'Phone is required'  
                            )
                        ),
                        'location' => array(
                            'required' => array(
                                'rule' => 'notBlank',
                                'message' => 'Loacation is required'  
                            )
                        ),
                        'business_name' => array(
                            'required' => array(
                                'rule' => 'notBlank',
                                'message' => 'Business Name is required'  
                            )
                        ),
                        'document' => array(
                            'required' => array(
                                'rule' => 'notBlank',
                                'message' => 'Document is required'  
                            )
                        ),
                        'doc_file' => array(
                            'required' => array(
                                'rule' => 'notBlank',
                                'message' => 'Document is required'  
                            )
                        ),
                        'pname' => array(
                            'required' => array(
                                'rule' => 'notBlank',
                                'message' => 'Name is required'  
                            )
                        ),
                        'pemail' => array(
                            'required' => array(
                                'rule' => 'notBlank',
                                'message' => 'Please enter a Valid Email Id'  
                            )
                        ),
                        'pOfc_phone' => array(
                            'required' => array(
                                'rule' => 'notBlank',
                                'message' => 'Please enter a Phone Number'  
                            )
                        ),
                        'pdesignation' => array(
                            'required' => array(
                                'rule' => 'notBlank',
                                'message' => 'Designation is Required'  
                            )
                        ),                    
                    );                    
                } 


                ?>
```

Comment: how is your save function in the controller ??

Comment: Actually i was using ajax form serialize to insert into Mysql database

Comment: Ya you can use serialize but still you need a function to save your data...
if url: '/invl_exams/userprice' is your url then there should be logic to save your values..

Comment: Price_submit function i have included inside the controller which will insert into DB but its not inserting

Comment: Please once again go through the code i have done some changes

Comment: But in your url yor function name is submitprice.

Comment: using  Router::connect('/submitprice', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'price_submit')); This submitprice url will take the action of price_submit function which i have written inside the controller

Comment: thats ok then..if so serialize your $priceData within controller $this->set(array('priceData'=>$priceData,'_serialize'=>'priceData'));

Comment: Ya i have added the code above $this->Price->create(); but its not saving the data

Comment: thats ok then..if so serialize your $priceData within controller $this->set(array('priceData'=>$priceData,'_serialize'=>'priceData')); and check the response within ajax request to be sure if data are comming .

Comment: I used the code within the success call back function curl bracket but its not showing anything

Comment: If i use the code my user dropdown not displaying the textboxes

Comment: Comment all codes within the function..and just return something from there ! and check within ajax..

Comment: I used $('#msg').html(strMessage); inside the success call back function curl bracket but on submitting the form again its showing the form once again in the div id="msg"

Comment: Is there any other way to insert dynamic input fiels into DB other than ajax form serialize

Comment: what you are doing is better as it does not reload bowser..but you have to debug well and find out if your request is comming to cntroller..It will be easy if you follow cakephp convention..

Comment: If click event doesn't work You can try submit event..

Comment: Still i didn't get solution for the post which i had send long back